# iOS programmatically alter uiview layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit

I have a page on my iOS app laid out based upon the following diagram, which is as follows.

- Dark grey box  = navbar
- Light grey box = UIView (for presentation, with some nice dropshadow etc)
- Black border   = UIView (again, with nice shadow, different background colour etc)
- 2 text fields
- Pink box = another view to display after an event.

[image: layout]

Currently, I'm laying out everything with initWithFrame, and explicitly setting the frame of every item, which I know is probably not great (I'm new to ios development, so please point me in the right direction).

What i'm trying to acheive is that when some text is entered into the 2nd text field the pink box to reveal, and the superviews to correctly respond, and layout nicely around the new field.

I have no issue with the event itself, and I could easliy just change the frame of each UIView in turn, but I feel this is wrong, and would love some pointers. I'd also ultimately like the pink box to animate in, and therefore the containing views to animate with it.

I hope i've explained myself thoroughly. Many thanks

Comment: Have you read [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html) ? The newer approach is `Handling Layout Changes Automatically Using Autoresizing Rules` and the universal is `Tweaking the Layout of Your Views Manually`.

Comment: you should implement layoutSubviews in your UIView subclass and set the view frames there

Comment: Thanks @A-Live, that document really helped. I sorted it with autoresizesSubviews = YES!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the event triggering that you'd like to then run animations off the back of, that's quite a straightforward thing to do.

```
- (void)myEventMethod:(id)sender {
  // Do your event stuff here
  // Animate the pink box into view
  // The below assumes the pink box is hidden behind the blackView and you'd like to drop it down 44 pixels over 0.3 seconds - hopefully correct - haven't tested
  // need to be careful as it'll move down 44px every time myEventMethod: is triggered
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                        delay:0.0
                      options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                   animations:^{
                   CGRect pinkboxEndFrame = CGRectMake(self.blackView.frame.origin.x, self.blackView.frame.origin.y + 44, self.pinkbox.frame.size.width, self.pinkbox.frame.size.height);
                   [self.pinkbox setFrame:pinkboxEndFrame];
                   }
                   completion:nil];

}
```

Just update the above with any other animations you'd like to do to the other views.

For more info on animating views you can check out the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/animatingviews/animatingviews.html) from Apple.